# employing AES algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, security, cryptography, aes

I have employed an AES algorithm in order to encrypt files within a GUI. I was wondering if my algorithm is secure. Could I change anything to improve it? Is my IV secure and is it producing different random numbers each time? Am I transferring the salt successfully?

I know that I could improve this by making separate classes for the different methods however I am just doing this within the main for now. I'm quite new to cryptography so any feedback would be greatly appreciated!
    // author @Alex Matheakis 
    public class AESFileEncryption {

```
// password to encrypt the file - how long should password be?
private static final String password = "UxIpOqSdNmSTuxZaShPu";

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    // file to be encrypted
    FileInputStream inF = new FileInputStream(GUI.AESinFile); // 'AESinFile' is a JFileChooser method from my GUI class

    // encrypted file
    FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream("encrypted_file.des");

    // generate and write the salt
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    sr.nextBytes(salt);
    outF.write(salt);

    // generate key
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256); // salt, iteration count, key strength
    SecretKey tmp = skf.generateSecret(keySpec);
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES"); // returns key

    // initialise the cipher with secure padding
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    AlgorithmParameters p = cipher.getParameters();

    // iv used when initializing the cipher to make text more random

    byte[] iv = p.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    outF.write(iv);

    // file encryption
    byte[] input = new byte[64];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = inF.read(input)) != -1) {
        byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
        if (output != null)
            outF.write(output);
    }

    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
    if (output != null)
        outF.write(output);
        System.out.println("file encrypted");


    inF.close();
    outF.flush();
    outF.close();
    // inputScanner.close();

}

}
```

Comment: @adot710 I rolled back that edit since it looked like a mistake, maybe try again if it was formatting related.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

Line 105 is a typo. The indentation suggests its only executed if output is not null.

But it's actually unrelated to the if statement.

You should always use curly braces even if execution is only 1 line long. This goes for all statements: while, if, do, etc.

Comment: Good spot didn't see that thanks, does the rest of my code seem okay?